# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: to see table click here]

```
ggplot(data = tall_summary_min_interval, aes(x = min_used, y = users, group = member_casual)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post pictures of data since we cannot copy/paste that into R for testing.

Comment: Your code looks fine. As you provided no data I could only guess that one reason four your error may be that in your data the column is named `min_uesd` while in your code it is `min_used`.

Comment: Check your column names again.  I think there is a typo.